# Preprocessors in C #if and #ifdef

Tags: c

While learning about c preprocessor `#if` I came across this particular statement describing the term expression in its syntax given on gcc.gnu.org , syntax : -

```
#if *expression*  
    controlled text  
#endif
```

**Question**:--Can someone explain what the following statement means in context of *expression* described in the above syntax :-
**statement** :-In C , expression may contain Identifiers that are not macros, which are all considered to be the number zero. This allows you to write `#if MACRO` instead of `#ifdef MACRO`, if you know that MACRO, when defined, will always have a nonzero value. Function-like macros used without their function call parentheses are also treated as zero.

In some contexts this shortcut is undesirable. The `-Wundef` option causes GCC to warn whenever it encounters an identifier which is not a macro in an `#if`.

---

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise, what is unclear for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In C , expression may contain Identifiers that are not macros, which are all considered to be the number zero.

This means that, if you have a `#if` directive such as:

```
#if X == 3
```

and `X` is not defined as a preprocessor macro, then it is replaced with `0`, so the directive is processed as if it were:

```
#if 0 == 3
```

That is standard C behavior. GCC’s `-Wundef` option asks the compiler to warn you when this occurs.

There is one exception; the identifier `defined` is treated specially. If `defined identifier` or `defined (identifier)` appears in a `#if` directive, it is replaced by 1 or 0 according to whether `identifier` is a defined macro or not.

> This allows you to write `#if MACRO` instead of `#ifdef MACRO`, if you know that MACRO, when defined, will always have a nonzero value.

Due to the above substitution, `#if MACRO` will become either `#if replacement` if `MACRO` is a defined object-like macro or `#if 0` if not. Then we have the following cases:

- `MACRO` is an object-like macro that expands to something that is not zero: `#if MACRO` evaluates it as true, and `#ifdef MACRO` evaluates its condition as true.
- `MACRO` is an object-like macro that expands to something that is zero: `#if MACRO` evaluates it as false, and `#ifdef MACRO` evaluates its condition as true.
- `MACRO` is not defined as an object-like macro: `#if MACRO` becomes `#if 0` and is evaluated as false, and `#ifdef MACRO` evaluates its condition as false.

Thus, `#if MACRO` and `#ifdef MACRO` behave the same if `MACRO` is not an expression with value zero.

Note: An object-like macro has no arguments, as in:

```
#define MACRO (3+4)
```

and a function-like macro has arguments, as in:

```
#define MACRO(x) (3+(x))
```

> Function-like macros used without their function call parentheses are also treated as zero.

If `MACRO` is defined as a function-like macro, then, in `#if MACRO`, no macro replacement is performed. This is because function-like macros are replaced only if they are followed by parentheses, as in `#if MACRO(3)`. So, after being rejected for macro replacement, it proceeds to the substitution of identifiers with `0`, becoming `#if 0`.

Comment: Thanx for helping out